# CGAL AABB tree: Inserting arbitrarily shaped 3D polyhedral surfaces

Tags: cgal, aabb

I know CGAL's AABB tree can store 3D polyhedral surfaces if the faces can be defined as triangles or tetrahedra. I also know CGAL supports alpha shapes, where 3D points could be turned into a 3D surface (using Delaunay triangulation). What I would like to know is if there is an easy way to insert a 3D shape defined by a list of 3D points and edges into an AABB tree (e.g., without having to list out separate tetrahedral and triangular faces)? Perhaps using an alpha shape?

Comment: You are talking about points and edges, so are you only interested in working with edges and not 3D polygons? For example [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/AABB_tree_2AABB_segment_3_example_8cpp-example.html) you have an AABB-tree of segments.

Comment: I want to insert 3D polyhedra. I just think it would be easier for the people who will be specifying the shapes to provide a list of bounding points, or bounding points and edges rather than have to individually specify triangular faces or tetrahedral shapes making up each polyhedron. I could get a list of cells from the alpha shape and then use these one at a time to build up the polyhedra, but  this doesn't seem like great solution.